# Load currentUser using Sprig with Blitz

Tags: templating, plugin-sprig, plugin-blitz

I'm having an issue with Sprig + Blitz Caching. I'm trying to load a user image if `currentUser` exists, though I'm having an issue with the caching. Sprig is loading in the unregistered user photo when logged in. I'm unsure if it's setup right.

```
      {{ sprig('components/_componentUser', {}, {
        's-trigger': 'refresh, load'
      }) }}
```

Then in my `_componentUser`

```
  {% if currentUser %}
            <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link py-3" href="/account" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="My Account">
                  <div class="account-circle">
                        <img src="{{ craft.gravatar.url(currentUser.email) }}" width="34" class="rounded-circle"/>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item position-relative">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/account" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="My Account">
                  <div class="account-circle">
                        <span class="material-icons" data-icon="account_circle"></span>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-sprig/issues/118

The code is correct and what you are experiencing is likely due to local browser caching.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Appreciated.